# Is it OK to ask for suggestions concerning a table layout?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am currently making a table in LaTeX. I also received great help from asking two questions on the site but I forgot to add a parameter to the table so now I basically have to re-make it.

I could just add the parameter, but I'm fond of nice-looking things (and hard challenges eheh), so I couldn't help making it harder than it could have been; my mind forced me to re-organize everything and provide the best organization for a lot of information in a single table.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a solution. I might find it as soon as I post this question (eheh) but I wanted to know if it would be on topic and OK for me to ask a question looking for suggestions about a table layout. Something along the lines of "How can I organize it the best way?" (more or less).

Is there a site policy for this particular issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question would be ontopic if you would ask like "How can I structure it in the best way using LaTeX" or similar. Besides being ontopic, try to be not too vague.

Both the question and answers could deal with general suggestions for table improvement, your table serving just as example. Otherwise it's possible that the question would be "too localized" and perhaps it would be closed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll think about that and see if I can think of a nice question to post also for future reference. :)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is o.k. on tex.sx, but it would probably get better input on [graphicdesign.sx](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). If you are more interested on better code, there's also [codereview.sx](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's not a matter of graphic design, but also about ease-of-use, both when reading and compiling. :P